# Set div height and scroll accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

There are a lot of questions related to this question.

I have tried almost all that I could probably find, but still did not serve the purpose I was looking for.

My page structure is like this.

```
<div>
   <header id="status">
     // The content within this section changes dynamically
   </header>
   <div id="summary">
     // This div height should adjust accordingly and have a vertical scroll if needed
   </div>
</div>
```

I am currently using the following script to do this, but I am not able to scroll to the bottom when ever the text in the `header` is lengthy.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var headerHt = $("#status").height();
    summaryHeight = h - headerHt;
    $('#summary').css("height", summaryHeight + 'px'); $('#summary').css({ "overflow-y": "auto", "overflow-x": "hidden" });

$(window).resize(function () {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var headerHt = $("#status").height();
    summaryHeight = h - headerHt;
    $('#summary').css("height", summaryHeight + 'px'); $('#summary').css({ "overflow-y": "auto", "overflow-x": "hidden" });
```

`min-height` and 'max-height' did not help me.

Please help me with this, I have been stuck with this for more than a month. Earlier I was able to achieve this by setting the height to a value, but with the header height changing, that approach will not work.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you try to achieve. You say "scroll accordingly", "adjust accordingly" and "the purpose I was looking for", but I don't see in the description what final result you want.

Comment: @ConnorsFan What I need is `#summary` height should adjust accordingly, if the content overflows then a scroll bar should come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use `flexbox`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#status {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
#summary {  
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <header id="status">
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
   </header>
   <div id="summary">
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>

     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

*Side note: This is how an IE8/9 user will see the above `flex`, and since their is less than 2% of them out there, I think is a great fallback and keep your code clean*

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  /*display: flex;*/
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}
#status {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
#summary {  
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <header id="status">
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
     The content within this section changes dynamically<br>
   </header>
   <div id="summary">
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>

     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
     This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution also, stackoverflow had this solution, but somehow did not work.. I will try again and update

Comment: I tried this, does not scroll to the bottom of the `div`. What does Flex exactly do? @lgson

Comment: @Jil What does not scroll to which div's bottom?? ... Could you make a screen dump image with a mark how you mean it should behave?

Comment: Left aligned. The solution you gave works fine but I am able to scroll to the bottom when I add more padding to the bottom. If I remove the padding The scroll bar is not visible, the text overflows but still the scroll bar is not shown. Attaching an image to show what I am exactly referring to. @lgson

Comment: The `header` should be fixed, no scroll bar for that section. `#summary` should have a scroll bar when the text exceeds the page height.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wLoL4t8f/2/ updated the fiddle :) The scroll bar is not visible. But if I add padding the scroll bar shows up. I want the scroll bar to be shown once the content exceeds

Comment: Perfect.. Exactly what I wanted. You removed the `flex` from the `#status` . Can you explain me what you exactly did?

Comment: Works perfectly. Just as I Wanted. Thanks a lot :) :) Helped me from this.. Been breaking my head over this for more than a month.. Thank a ton :)

Comment: @Jil Removed the `flex` as it is not needed. Change padding to only be at top, right and left, 0 at bottom `padding: 20px 10px 0 10px;`

Comment: I am still facing some issue with the scroll bar :( I forgot to mention that I had another div above it with the height set to 100% and overflow: hidden.. because of that the scroll for the #summary section is not till the div end. @lgson

Comment: @Jil Then you need to update your question with the full html/css you use, or else I can't give an appropriate answer

Comment: This is very weird. I added the same styles to the fiddle and works fine, but does not in my page.. Will bang my head over it.. Thanks for the help

Comment: I was going through the compatibility of flex with different browsers and I saw that this is not compatible with IE Version <10 . can you suggest another way to do achieve this ?

Comment: @Jil How far down on IE versions do you need?

Comment: @Jil Are you aware of the user statistics on those is less than 2%? ... I recommend you just leave it as is. I updated my answer with a 2:nd sample, showing how it will look in IE8/9. I let my website behave like that,  ... and if you really can't do that, combine my flex with Anhtony's jQuery.

Comment: Thanks a lot @lgson :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain. Flexbox is the new way to do this and has some good polyfills but if you are already committed to jquery then I have created a JSfiddle with a quick scratch of what I think you are trying to acheive:

https://jsfiddle.net/c0un7z3r0/t9dde970/

The Jquery was fine, it just needed the css to position the elements so that they behave as expected.

```
#container{
  position:absolute;
  top;0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:100vh;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:white;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
#status{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:red;
}
#summary{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  background:blue;
}
```

Its also worth pointing out, to get the child elements of #summary to overflow to the right of the screen (rather than down) requires you to set some rules for the elements so that they dont linebreak when they hit the right edge of the screen, something like:

```
#summary{
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
#summary > #summary-content{
    display:inline-block;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: The contents of the `#summary` should not overflow to the right. The page design is such that the content should overflow down.

Comment: I do not need a scroll bar for the `#status` . `#summary` should start just from the point where the `#status` ends and that needs to have a scrollbar when the text exceeds the page height.

Comment: In that case it should work just fine as it is without the additional css at the bottom of my answer. From the description you said:

"This div height should adjust accordingly and have a horizontal scroll if needed"

...So i thought that you wanted it so if the content inside #summary was larger than it can contain rather than having to scroll down to see everything, youd need to scroll across. I hope this helps. If im not understanding the question please elaborate further in what the desired behaviour should be.

Comment: oopss.. did I say horizontally :P

Comment: Works perfectly. Just as I Wanted. Thanks a lot :) :) Helped me from this.. Been breaking my head over this for more than a month.. Thank a ton :)

Comment: Yes I did.. but I am still facing some issue with the scroll bar :( I forgot to mention that I had another div above it with the height set to 100% and overflow: hidden.. because of that the scroll for the `#summary` section is not till the div end

Comment: Im still not clear on what the desired outcome is. If you only want summary to scroll check out this edit:

https://jsfiddle.net/c0un7z3r0/p9nhbyt8/1/

Btw, I hate to be presumptious but I think you accepted the wrong answer (no offence, I am just grinding my stack overflow profile and accepted answers go a long way)

Comment: Sorry if that offended you, the reason I accepted the other answer is, 1. Less lines of code. Flex did the work. 2. His answer was the first. Unfortunately stackoverflow does not allow me to accept 2 answers. And man you have 286 credits, mine is not even 50, :P .. Really very very long way to go :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p9nhbyt8/2/ modified your code and I do not see the scroll bar coming up once the text crosses the page height.

Comment: No offence taken, I am sorry for assuming you had selected the wrong answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set height of both div with vh unit. For example set height of header 30vh and set height of #summary 70vh. That's it.